# Log with GUI in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, components

I have tried many objects in Xcode's object library, but I can't seem to find the correct objects.

What I am trying to do is create a log for my app, for development purposes, but also for any future users who just feel like having a log. I don't want to use `NSLog(NSString)`. I need an Obj-C equivalent of Java's javax.swing.JTextArea that has the following properties:
1. can be contained in a scroll pane (and how do I do this)
2. can be set to un-editable (Java equivalent of `myTextArea.setEditable(false)`)
3. (in code) can receive `\n` as "new line" (shouldn't be a problem)

Does this exist, and if not, how can I create something similar (for example covering a text area with a layer)?

Thanks

Comment: Which platform, iOS and/or OS X?

Comment: OS X, I forgot to add that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocoa's `NSTextView` class fits this perfectly. It can be found in the object library as "text view". It can be set to non-editable in the properties inspector and can receive `"\n"` as a new line. It already has scroll bars.